Event profile missing from page
We have two profiles set up to be used for events: one for the top of the page, one for the bottom. Everything is working fine on our Drupal7 site.
I just did the process for upgrading to D10 (install Civi, import old structure into new db, import old data into new db, connect new db in the settings file).
The profile for the top of the page on event registrations is completely missing. I tried creating a new profile to make certain there wasn't something wrong with the one we were using. The new one only had first name, last name, and email on it. It doesn't show, either. The bottom profile fields are showing fine.
I checked the source for the page and the fields aren't there. Same thing happens when I switch to a different theme (right now I'm just using the default Olivero theme while we finish development).
I have debugging and backtrace turned on, but nothing is popping up for the page.
The page knows the fields should be there, as if you try to use the page to sign up for an event, it tells you that the mandatory fields (name and email) aren't filled out.
Using CiviCRM 5.79.0 on Drupal 10.

I can't reproduce on a simple setup. You could try to debug what is happening in this function when $name=='customPre' ? Although it's hard to think why it would depend on CMS. It does look at permissions, which might be different, although I'd expect any checks to be the same for top and bottom sections.

How would I do that?
Oh, and here's a sample link: https://nl-sandbox.xyz/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=5941

Is your top profile called "Contact Information"? That seems to be displaying. If you inspect the html it's in a <div> with custom_pre-section, and that contains a <fieldset> with crm-profile-id-36.

Yes, but it's not showing for me when I inspect the html. Even when I search for crm-profile-id-36

That's really odd. It's definitely there for me <fieldset class="crm-profile crm-profile-id-36 crm-profile-name-Trainings_Contact_Information"><legend>Contact Information</legend>. Try a different browser to see if it's maybe a browser cache thing? Try as anonymous?

Yes, that is really weird. It's showing in Firefox, but not Chrome. Not even in incognito. Thanks. More problems to run down, I guess...

If it helps, which it probably doesn't, I was using firefox but it also shows for me in chrome. So maybe a chrome plugin you have or ???

Yeah, I can get it to show for me in Chrome when I'm not logged in. But nada when I'm logged in. So weird.
